# How to make component disappear when scroll down in Angular?

Tags: angular, scroll, components

I am looking for a simple way to make a different header appear when the normal one is scrolled down.
I have been looking for many solution but they're all involving long code..

So here is the solution I found but that isn't working since y doesn't implement itself..

Here is the TypeScript

```
import { Component, OnInit, HostListener } from '@angular/core';`

...

export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit{

    y = window.scrollY;

    myID = document.getElementById("header");

    myID2 = document.getElementById("header2");

ngOnInit() {
        this.myScrollFunc();
        window.addEventListener("scroll", this.myScrollFunc);
      }

      myScrollFunc() {
        if (this.y >= 150) {
          this.myID2.className = "bottomMenu hide"
          this.myID.className = "bottomMenu show"
        } else {
          this.myID2.className = "bottomMenu show"
          this.myID.className = "bottomMenu hide"
        }
      };

    }
```

The HTML

```
<div id="header" class="bottomMenu show"> ... </div>

<div id="header2" class="bottomMenu hide"> ... </div>
```

And the .css

```
.hide {
  opacity: 0;
  left: -100%;
}
.show {
  opacity: 1;
  left: 0;
}
```

This apparently is supposed to work and looks simple but it doesn't work for me..

EDIT : If you have a simpler way I am also open, the solution isn't mainly to correct this one.

EDIT 2 : Still no answer, if anyone have an idea, or if there is a simpler solution, like if (position !=0) { y = 1 } else { y = 0 } and i'd add y in some ngIf in the HTML... ?

EDIT 3 : I finally found a solution, here is my code if someone has the same problem :

HTML

```
<div id="header" *ngIf="scrolled == 0"> ... </div>
<div id="header2" *ngIf="scrolled == 1"> ... </div>
```

TypeScript

```
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit{

  scrolled = 0;

  @HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
  onWindowScroll($event) {
    const numb = window.scrollY;
    if (numb >= 50){
      this.scrolled = 1;
    }
    else {
      this.scrolled = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Easier than long listener

Thank you very much for your help in advance !

Comment: can you provide your full html template to see which element event you listening to

Comment: I guess I only have this in the .ts : window.addEventListener("scroll", this.myScrollFunc); ... Thought it was enough for the listener

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTML

```
<div id="header" *ngIf="scrolled == 0"> ... </div>
<div id="header2" *ngIf="scrolled == 1"> ... </div>
```

TypeScript

```
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit{

  scrolled = 0;

  @HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
  onWindowScroll($event) {
    const numb = window.scrollY;
    if (numb >= 50){
      this.scrolled = 1;
    }
    else {
      this.scrolled = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Easier than long listener

Answer (score 1):

I am updated your code try this.

```
import { Component, OnInit, HostListener } from '@angular/core';`

...

export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit{

    y = window.scrollY;
    myID = document.getElementById("header");
    myID2 = document.getElementById("header2");

ngOnInit() {}

@HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
onWindowScroll($event) {
          if (this.y >= 150) {
          this.myID2.className = "bottomMenu hide"
          this.myID.className = "bottomMenu show"
        } else {
          this.myID2.className = "bottomMenu show"
          this.myID.className = "bottomMenu hide"
        }
}

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll work on the *ngIf solution and see if it works first !

Answer (score 1):

If you are using angular and want to hide certain elements you should just use `*ngIF` which will render or not the element and there's no need to apply css to hide it, and since you are only showing 1 element or the other you can just bind both to the same variable but with inverse condition.

```
<div id="header" *ngIf="!scrolled" class="bottomMenu"> ... </div>

<div id="header2" *ngIf="scrolled" class="bottomMenu"> ... </div>
```

And in your component all left to do is turn scrolled to on if it get past your desired height.

```
import { Component, OnInit, HostListener } from '@angular/core';`

...

export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit{

    scrolled = false;

    @HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
    onWindowScroll($event) {
        this.scrolled = $event.srcElement.scrollTop >= 150;
    }
}
```

**Edit: I added the HostListener from upinder kumar answer since that's the proper way to register to events in angular.**

Edit 2 : I in the past have implemented something similar to this but didn't used a hardcoded px (in your case you using 150 px ) size to scroll event but yet instead I calculated that my header would change after 10% of the scroll has been moved with the following expression :

```
this.scrolled = $event.srcElement.scrollTop / $event.srcElement.scrollHeight > 0.1 ;
```

Comment: Oh thank you I didn't think about the *ngIf solution here, I still have some problems, I try to fix them and get back to you if this still doesn't work !

Comment: I think the listener doesn't work, nothing happens when I scroll down..

Comment: @Skimar Yes then you should use the upinder kumar approach with the ngIf approach , instead applying different css

Comment: without the ngif you mean ? Ok I'll try his solution then

Comment: @Skimar No, you want to use the ngIf, because it still makes no sense to apply css to hide elements, plus you don't want to do it via the component if that would be the case you would apply via a ngClass. Just combine both solutions i will edit mine to include all.

Comment: Ok thank you, I'm working on it since, but still seems not to work... It displays the first so for this I think it's ok, the *ngIf works, but on the listener he tells me 2 advices : "Parameter '$event' implicitly has an 'any' type, but a better type may be inferred from usage." & "'$event' is declared but its value is never read.", in the onWindowScroll, I even tested with 10 as the y value but same..

Comment: @Skimar check my edit to acess the event correct scroll value

Comment: I'm sorry still not working.. The problem is really the listener I think because even when I put 1 on the y value, the second I scroll the first header should atleast disappear, but it's still here.. Might there be some import or something I could have forgotten ?

Comment: @Skimar I left the 150 px because I thought that was the value that your element has to be scrolled if that value is to be dynamic or another you can change from 150 px to anything else , now that value has to obtained from the rest of your code css

Comment: 150px is the header height, yes

Comment: @Skimar okay then do a console.log(event) and see what it returns if there you can navigate till the event.srcElement.scrollTop property

Comment: thank you, apparently it sees it, I cannot find any value on the console, it shows this : Event {isTrusted: true, type: "scroll", target: document, currentTarget: Window, eventPhase: 3, …}
bubbles: true
cancelBubble: false
cancelable: false
composed: false
currentTarget: null
defaultPrevented: false
eventPhase: 0
isTrusted: true
path: (2) [document, Window]
returnValue: true
srcElement: document
target: document
timeStamp: 33723.884999984875
type: "scroll"
__proto__: Event

Comment: @Skimar have tried using $event.srcElement.scrollTop?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201087/discussion-between-skimar-and-tiago-silva).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, using `@HostListener('window:scroll')` did not work for me. For moderns browsers, you can use the **wheel** event (*WheelEvent*) instead.

I get the scroll for the entire app and share among the components, so that I can do whatever I want with the event.

`share.service.ts`

```js
  public isScrolledUp = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(null);

  public addScroll(isScroll: boolean) {
    this.isScrolledUp.next(isScroll);
  }
```

`app.component.ts`

```js
  constructor(private sharedS: SharedService){}

  public onScroll(event: WheelEvent) {
    // Move Up (negative)
    // Move Down (positive)
    this.sharedS.addScroll(event.deltaY > 0);
  }
```

`app.component.html`

```html
<div (wheel)="onScroll($event)">
    <!--Here goes your components-->
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Then, any component you like just import the `SharedService` and subscribe the property **isScrolledUp**.

`any.component.ts`

```js
  private sub: Subscription;
  public isScrollUp: boolean; // you can do whatever you want. Ex: hide some buttons
  constructor(private sharedS: SharedService){}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.sub = this.sharedS.isScrolledUp.subscribe((res) => this.isScrollUp = res);
  }
```

`any.component.html`

```html
<footer *ngIf="!isScrollUp"></footer>
<button *ngIf="isScrollUp"></button>
```